# Perl reads only the last line of my file?

Tags: perl

OK I have a file which is a list of over 5000 names, one line each;
the file is a txt file generated with microsoft excel.
The following code gave me an output of 1.

```
open FILEHANDLE, "< listname_FC2-3ss>0.txt";
chomp (my @genelist = <FILEHANDLE>);
close FILEHANDLE;
print "the number of item in the list is ";
print scalar @genelist;
```

I'm using a '10 macbook air, perl 5.12.I tried to output the list and its the last line of the file.
But I tried the code on a tiny version of 10 names which I extracted by hand myself and it worked perfectly fine, so i reckon it's got something to do with the delimiter?

Please help.

Ian

Comment: What does `wc listname_FC2-3ss\>0.txt` tell?

Comment: 0    7486  142233 listname_FC2-3ss>0.txt

Comment: How are each line formatted in your file?

Comment: So `wc` is saying you have 0 lines in the file. You should open the file in a text editor that knows about various line-ending habits (e.g. vim)

Comment: It would be great to get rid of `>` and then `hexdump -C yourfile | head`

Comment: ok msw vim tells me that these names are separated with ^M but i dont seem to be able to split it directly in perl...

Comment: right i reckon it worked. i input the file into one string and split with \r. thanks heaps!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with

```
local $/ = "\r";
```

before file reading. It changes the input record separator to the `"\r"` character.

Comment: thanks, I have the same problem, but in Xcode debug console. Don't know, that Mac uses `\r`, not `\n`